# Erreur : package or namespace load failed for ‘conflicted’:

Tags: r, shiny, merge-conflict-resolution

When I try to load the package conflicted, i have this error :

```
Erreur : package or namespace load failed for ‘conflicted’:
 .onAttach a échoué dans attachNamespace() pour 'conflicted', détails :
  appel : NULL
  erreur : `fn` must be an R function, not a primitive function
```

I think that this error provides of my code when a make a merge from some data, because i have this also error :

```
Warning: Error in merge: arguments inutilisés (by.x = c("OP", "Batchnum"), by.y = c("PO Label", "Batch Number"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
```

I think too that it's a problem between a package conflicted and base with a "merge"

Help me please.

Comment: Did you use `library(conflicted)` to load your package? Also, what is the code you used to merge the datasets that resulted in the error?

Comment: Yes i used l library(conflicted).I understood my mistake, in fact I also had the bit64 package.

Comment: Did you remember to use quotation marks, e.g. `library("conflicted")`?